# Is there any way to parse invalid HTML?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I need to parse invalid HTML files that contain several random elements (like BODY) in random lines all over file.
I tried to parse it as XML, but with no luck since this file has invalid XML structure as well(a lot of incorrect attributes in random elements over file).
HtmlAgilityPack has failed to read this file as well. It's only reading file before first incorrect  element and nothing after it.

Here is small example of such file:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>My title</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY leftmargin=9 topmargin=7 >
    <TABLE>
        <TR>
            <TD>Test</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>Test</TD>
            <TD>Test<TD>
        </TR>
            <BODY> <-- This is the point where HtmlAgilityPack is stuck --!>
                <TR>
                    <TD>Test</TD>
                    <TD>Test</TD>
                </TR>
                <TR>
            </BODY>
        <TR>
        <TD><FONT>Test</FONT></TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
</BODY>
```

I'm trying to parse info from that table.

Comment: It's hard enough to parse valid HTML, partly because of the definition of 'invalid'!

Comment: if AgilityPack can't read it, I think your fragment is really in a bad shape. if the document is on the file system you can read it with Streams but for parsing it, consider that if a browser is unable to render it and AgilityPack can't parse it, either you leave it or you build your own parser which does not break even with that kind of content. Can you show a snippet of such broken html content?

Comment: Why do you need to parse?  Are you trying to collect errors and display them?  Are you trying to correct the errors automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let Internet Explorer do the hard work for you - it will do its best to "repair" the broken tag structure into something it understands (which is technically valid XML with correct tag pairings etc.).

Open the HTML in [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) (or [Windows.Controls.WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx) if you prefer WPF libraries), then you can walk through the DOM via [Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.document.aspx) property. The DOM will always be correct, no matter how broken the original source was.

No third party libraries needed.

Comment: @Kevin You mean how to retrieve specific tags from the Document property? Check out documentation for the HtmlDocument class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.aspx , you can use methods like GetElementsByName, GetElementsById etc., or walk through the complete DOM starting with Body property (it has collection of its children, its children have their own children...). EDIT: Damn, the comment disappeared :)

Answer (score 3):

We parsed web pages with invalid html with [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). As I remember it did a pretty good job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SgmlReader](http://developer.mindtouch.com/SgmlReader). Of course if your html files are very incorrect, it won't help you.